# Modal form doesn't appear in tray until minimized and owner-form is clicked once. How do I make it appear?

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

("Click on owner-form" doesn't count. :))

I have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm2.Owner = this;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem years ago. My solution was to play with winapi und push the window to the front. I you want to go this way look for interop. I found the functions. I should be `SetForegroundWindow` and `SetFocus`.

Comment: Do you mean taskbar?  Given that your snippet is utterly insufficient to repro the problem, let's tackle this another way.  Dialogs should never display a taskbar button.  Set the ShowInTaskbar property to false.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. Yes, I meant the taskbar. But why is it insufficient? (Regardless, I've updated the question.) Your solution creates a small window for the minimized modal-form. That's not good.

Comment: See your other question, modal windows can't be allowed to minimize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the owner setting from

```
frm2.Owner = this;
```

to

```
frm2.ShowDialog(this);
```

(Credit goes to [gerald-p-wright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8705194/939213))