# Why does modal-form disappear completely when minimized?

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

I'm trying to have the owner-form minimize when the modal-form is minimized. But when I minimize the modal-form – it disappears completely. (- I can click on the owner-form.)

How do I solve this?

I have:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm2.Owner = this;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

And:

```
class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm1;
    FormWindowState ws = new FormWindowState();

    public Form2()
    {
        SizeChanged += new EventHandler(Form2_SizeChanged);
    }

    void Form2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1 = (Form1)Owner;
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) 
        { 
            ws = frm1.WindowState; 
            frm1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; 
        }
        else frm1.WindowState = ws;
    }

}
```

(While trying this, I also ran into this: [Modal form doesn't appear in tray until minimized and owner-form is clicked once. How do I make it appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8704921/modal-form-doesnt-appear-in-tray-until-minimized-and-owner-form-is-clicked-once) )

Comment: Is `ShowInTaskBar` set to true for `Form2`?

Comment: @competent_tech I just tried that. Doesn't make a difference. But thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a:

```
Show();
```

At the end of Form2's event-handler.

Answer (score 4):

This is by design.  As part of the modality contract, showing a dialog disables all the other windows in the application.  When the user minimizes the dialog window, there are no windows left that the user can access.  Making the app unusable.  Winforms ensures this cannot happen by automatically closing the dialog when it gets minimized.

Clearly you'll want to prevent this from happening at all.  Set the MinimizeBox property to false.  The MaximizeBox property ought to be set to false as well, making both buttons disappear from the window caption.  Leaving room for the HelpButton btw.

Comment: a) Thanks for all the feedback. b) But I don't understand this reasoning. If a user wants to get my application out of the way in order to see another application, he wants my entire application out of his way. And why is it unusable? He can just click on the taskbar to get it back again.

Comment: I know that when I use SyncToy and it's working in the background, I minimize the modal-form of the Sync, and I'm bothered by the owner-form which cannot be minimized.

Comment: Well, avoid using broken apps as an example.  In Visual Studio, use Tools + Options as a good example.  Note the dialog's window caption, try to minimize VS.  Putting a window of another app in the foreground is of course no problem.

Comment: My mistake, it's the desktop that I can't see (And yes, I can open it as a folder of course...). Anyway, I see that what I was looking for is not an (easy) option. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall every needing this much code to get modal Windows to work.  I'm concerned by your comment 'I can click on the owner form', which leads me to believe that the form is nt being correctly set up as modal.  By defintion, modal forms must be dealt with before user control can return to the owner form.  Minimizinfg the modal form does not constitute properly 'dealing' with the modal form.

Here is some code that I have used in the past. Notes:  passing the owner as parameter in ShowDialog establishes the ownership relationship.  While I suspect your code works, I've not used it that way.

Also, when I have done this, I have not put any special code in the modal form, and have also disabled all the button in the upper right corner of the form; thereby insuring that the user cannot close, minimize, or maximize the modal form outside of any buttons I have provided.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. (And welcome to StackOverflow.) But what happens if the user wants to see what's behind my application? He needs to be able to minimize my _entire_ application. (And thanks for the `ShowDialog(this)`.)

Comment: Oh, I made the assumption that this (the modal form) was a simple dialog or pref screen that was temporarily opened over the main form.  The idea is that modal forms are temp.  The main app form should not be modal.

Comment: No, you were right. The modal-form _is_ a temporary form over the main form. (And it's the desktop that's hidden unless _all_ are minimized) But anyway, I see that what I was looking for is not an (easy) option. And by the way, your `ShowDialog(this)` solved my other question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Forms have a property `ShowInTaskbar`. If it is set to `false` then the form will never appear on the task bar, even when minimized.

Comment: I assume you're answering my other question. I just tried that. Doesn't make a difference. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the requirement where when minimizing a dialog form it should minimize the application and when restoring the application it should show the dialog again. Here's what I did:

*MainForm.cs*

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.Show(this, "Testing 123");
    }
}
```

*Form2.cs*

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    bool isMinimized;

    private Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Owner != null)
        {
            Owner.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MinimizeBox = Owner != null;
        if (Owner != null)
        {
            Owner.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void Form2_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Owner != null)
        {
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized && Owner.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                Owner.Enabled = true;
                Owner.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                isMinimized = true;
            }
            else if (isMinimized && Owner.WindowState != FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                Owner.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Show(Form owner, string message)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.label1.Text = message;

        if (owner != null)
            form2.Show(owner);
        else
            form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```