# C# minimizing dialog form doesn't parent form

Tags: c#, forms

I have problem with minimizing by program. It has main form and others, which I open by ShowDialog()

Problem is with minimizing these dialog forms. When my friend on Windows7 minimize this dialog, it minimize dialog and main form (dialog isn't in taskbar, I disabled it), but on my Windows7 only dialog is minimized like this

[image: screen of minimized dialog]

Is here any chance to minimize both forms? I found, that after form is minimized, Resize event is fired, so I made this

```
 private void ShowCode_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            main.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
```

but when I click on form in taskbar, main form is showed and dialog is closed, I don't know why?
Is here any chance, to always minimize it to taskbar?
And why on my PC it works this way, and on friend's other way? I don't know that I changed something in Windows settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly - I found a solution after asking a similar question.

Simply add a:    `Show();`
At the end of Form2's event-handler.

See about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8705846/939213) (and in the other answers.)

Comment: Thanks much. It doesn't work how I want, because minimized dialog is still above Start like on image, but main is minimized too. And why you should use `ShowDialog(this);` I red all topic with your questions, but I still don't understand.

Comment: @Arxeiss So un-accept my answer in order to get a better one. Perhaps I misunderstood your question.

Comment: No, I think that you understood correctly, but what I want isn't possible, how Hans Passant wrote, this is how dialog forms works. I want even small dialog on image to hide, but this is probably impossible, or very difficult, so this is enough for me.